# Mouse Movement via MotionSource (DSU)

Tags: mouse

I wish to control my mouse via my mobile's gyro, sideways. I was able to send motion like that using the android app called MotionSource which emits DSU input, and I am able to connect to games and the games recognize motion. I connect it by typing my phone's IP into the PC.

I want a way to be able to control my mouse movements via the motionsource app.